# What is a pytorch snapshot and a Dlib model? (Running Hopenet)

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, dlib

I am trying to make [Hopenet](https://github.com/natanielruiz/deep-head-pose) run on my computer, using the code on github

I have installed all required libraries. [This is my forked code](https://github.com/noamzilo/deep-head-pose), with `test_hopenet.py` updated to python 3.

I installed all required libraries, and using `pip install "pillow<7"` because of some old requirements.

```
python code/test_on_video_dlib.py --snapshot PATH_OF_SNAPSHOT --face_model PATH_OF_DLIB_MODEL --video PATH_OF_VIDEO --output_string STRING_TO_APPEND_TO_OUTPUT --n_frames N_OF_FRAMES_TO_PROCESS --fps FPS_OF_SOURCE_VIDEO
```

---

**It looks like I am missing some basic understanding which is supposed to be obvious:**

1. What is a SNAPSHOT? Where do I get one?
2. What is a Dlib Model? Where do I get the right one?

Again - I just want to make this code run, but I can't understand the instructions.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you know how to run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the dlib model you can use:
https://github.com/davisking/dlib-models/mmod_human_face_detector.dat.bz2

For the snapshot path you can use hopenet_robust_alpha1.pkl downloadable from the link "300W-LP, alpha 1, robust to image quality" under Pretrained Models section of Nathanial Ruiz's README.md

Comment: I have the same issue; I think that links are broken down. they did not work with me.